# Use livereload with webpack

Tags: webpack, livereload, webpack-dev-server

I would like to use livereload with webpack.
One option would be to use [hot module replacement](http://webpack.github.io/docs/hot-module-replacement.html) but in my case the js files **must be served from the file system** and not from a server (`localhost:<port>`).

So is there a way to integrate livereload with webpack without using grunt or gulp?

Comment: BrowserSync runs well as a standalone, although I'm not sure if would work to serve files from the local filesystem: http://www.browsersync.io/

Comment: thanks https://www.npmjs.com/package/browser-sync-webpack-plugin worked!

Comment: Why not just start a lightweight server?